# How to directly send a message to a contact through WhatsApp from my app with just one click?

Tags: android, whatsapp, sendmessage

I need to send a message from my app to a selected contact using WhatsApp. I have the contact name, number, ID and the message I want to send. just need to be able to send it without having to pick the contact in WhatsApp or the app to share the message.
I´ve tested several approaches but I have´nt found any working solution, the simplest is as follows:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
i.putExtra("sms_body", "message");
i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");  
startActivity(i);
```

With this approach the contact is selected automatically but then pops out that contact´s conversation inside WhatsApp and the worst part is that the message isn´t even there. With the message there I would only have to hit send and would be something, even when I need to do it all at once.

Thanks in advance!

PD: Thanks for the answer being root, but thats my last option, I just need to be able to send the message from a non rooted device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that as of now, because WhatsApp have not opened their APIs to the developers. The best you can do is as described [here](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012).

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Its strange, because apparently you can [select the contact in iOS](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013) by passing some extra params.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly speaking there's no public API available at this moment to share message for a specific contact. However if you aren't concerned with rooted device then you can follow the steps,

```
protected void whatsAppSendMessage(String[] paramArrayOfString, String paramString) {
  try {
   Shell shell = Shell.startRootShell();
   int j = paramArrayOfString.length;
   for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    String str3;
    long l1;
    long l2;
    int k;
    String str1;
    String str2;
    Random localRandom = new Random(20L);

    Log.d("AUTO",
      "ps | grep -w 'com.whatsapp' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill");
    commandsTestOnClick("ps | grep -w 'com.whatsapp' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill");

    str3 = paramArrayOfString[i] + "@s.whatsapp.net";
    l1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    l2 = l1 / 1000L;
    k = localRandom.nextInt();

    str1 = "sqlite3 /data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db \"INSERT INTO messages (key_remote_jid, key_from_me, key_id, status, needs_push, data, timestamp, MEDIA_URL, media_mime_type, media_wa_type, MEDIA_SIZE, media_name , latitude, longitude, thumb_image, remote_resource, received_timestamp, send_timestamp, receipt_server_timestamp, receipt_device_timestamp, raw_data, media_hash, recipient_count, media_duration, origin)VALUES ('"
      + str3
      + "', 1,'"
      + l2
      + "-"
      + k
      + "', 0,0, '"
      + paramString
      + "',"
      + l1
      + ",'','', '0', 0,'', 0.0,0.0,'','',"
      + l1
      + ", -1, -1, -1,0 ,'',0,0,0); \"";

    str2 = "sqlite3 /data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db \"insert into chat_list (key_remote_jid) select '"
      + str3
      + "' where not exists (select 1 from chat_list where key_remote_jid='"
      + str3 + "');\"";

    str3 = "sqlite3 /data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db \"update chat_list set message_table_id = (select max(messages._id) from messages) where chat_list.key_remote_jid='"
      + str3 + "';\"";

    Log.d("AUTO", str1);
    Log.d("AUTO", str2);
    Log.d("AUTO", str3);

    shell.add(
      new SimpleCommand(
        "chmod 777 /data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db"))
      .waitForFinish();
    shell.add(new SimpleCommand(str1)).waitForFinish();
    shell.add(new SimpleCommand(str2)).waitForFinish();
    shell.add(new SimpleCommand(str3)).waitForFinish();
   }
   shell.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

Tested and works perfectly even without opening the WhatsApp!

Original source,

[Whatsapp message share without opening whatsapp](http://siddhpuraamit.blogspot.in/)